# Field initialization when invoking a method overridden in a derived class from the constructor

Tags: javascript, inheritance, initialization

So I was messing with classes today when I found this weird bug/feature.

## First example

```js
class a { constructor () { this.load() } load () {} }
class b extends a { loaded = false; load () { this.loaded = true } }
const bInstance = new b()
console.log(bInstance.loaded);
```

I expected the result to be `true` but the actual result was `false`.

## Second example

```js
class a { a = true; constructor () { this.load() } load () {} }
class b extends a { b = true; load () { console.log(this.a, this.b) } }
const bInstance = new b()
```

Once again, I expected the `console.log` to log `true true` but it was `true undefined`.
The weirdest part is that `bInstance.a` is `true` and `bInstance.b` is `true`

Comment: You're calling `load` from within `a`'s constructor which has no attribute `b`. If you call `load` from `b`'s constructor you'll see both defined.

Answer (score 1):

Class fields will run only *after* a `super` call finishes. In your subclass, the `loaded = false` runs after the super calls `this.load()`, which results in `this.loaded = true` running. See below, logging will make things clearer:

```js
class a {
  constructor() {
    this.load()
  }
  load() {}
}
class b extends a {
  loaded = console.log('class field assigning to instance');
  load() {
    console.log('load() called');
    this.loaded = true
  }
}
const bInstance = new b()
```

In general:

```
class X {
  /* class fields here */
  constructor() {
    super();
```

is equivalent to

```
class X {
  constructor() {
    super();
    /* class fields assign to instance at this point */
```

It's not a bug, nor exactly a "feature", it's just how the language was designed.

```js
class a {
  a = true;
  constructor() {
    this.load()
  }
  load() {}
}
class b extends a {
  b = true;
  load() {
    console.log(this.a, this.b)
  }
}
const bInstance = new b()
```

For your second example - `load` is called by the super constructor, and, as mentioned previously, `super()` will run before class fields run - so your

```
class b extends a {
  b = true;
  load() {
    console.log(this.a, this.b)
  }
}
```

is equivalent to

```
class b extends a {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.b = true;
  }
  load() {
    console.log(this.a, this.b)
  }
}
```

Which makes it quite clear why `this.b` isn't assigned at the point that `load` is called inside the super constructor.